# Reusing a function among multiple components in React

Tags: react-native, code-reuse, react-component

I'm currently using the exact same function in multiple components in my react native app and I'd like it to move it into a separate component to be called every time need it.

I know how to reuse general components that take props and return something to render but I'm struggling with pure functions.

This is my function that runs a series of API calls and at last moves to a different screen.

```
const fetchMovieHandler = (movieId, movieTitle) => {
    function fetchData() {
      dispatch(movieMainActions.fetchMovie(movieId)).then((response) => {
        dispatch(movieCastActions.fetchCast(movieId)).then((response) => {
          dispatch(movieReviewsActions.fetchReviews(movieId)).then((response) => {              
              dispatch(movieSimilarActions.fetchSimilar(movieId)).then((response) => {
                  dispatch(movieRecommendActions.fetchRecommendations(movieId)).then((response) => {
                    props.navigation.navigate({
                        routeName: "MovieDetail",
                        params: {
                          assetId: movieId,
                          assetName: movieTitle,
                        },
                    });
                  });
              });
            });
        });
      });       
    }
    fetchData();
  };
```

Comment: i highly recommend using async await first to get your code a lot more readable

Comment: Understand your point however the question is not related on the style nor the content of the function itself. My objective is to save a specific function on a separate file which can then be reused and called by many other components. This has nothing to do with what's inside the function itself.